# Как использовать AES и RSA 2048 вместе?

Tags: c#, шифрование, rsa, aes

Подскажите можно ли использовать связку AES и RSA вместе?

P.S: И требуется ли для связки использование `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` или его можно исключить?

Comment: Вам для каких целей? Если для передачи данных по сети — просто возьмите TLS.

Comment: @andreymal, Нет, мне нужно для дома, чтобы можно было ключ rsa сохранить отдельно, и после использовать если нужно расшифровать какие-то данные на компьютере. Rsa хочу использовать просто под ключ чтобы, и этот ключ привязать к AES, но не знаю пока как реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Да, связку AES и RSA можно использвать вместе. Например, в рамках одной и той же сессии HTTPS RSA может быть использован для аутентификации, в то время как AES - для симметричного шифрования данных. Но никакой прямой стыковки между ними нет - это два разных алгоритма для двух разных видов шифрования, и никакой особой связи между ними нет.

Rfc2898DeriveBytes вообще создан для хэширования паролей (или с использованием паролей), и прямого отношения к RSA или к AES не имеет.

Comment: А есть ли какие-нибудь примеры использование ? Я ничего подобного не нашёл.

Comment: В исходниках каждого браузера, или, например, внутри cURL. Такое комбо - это просто staple food современной практической криптографии.

Comment: @rudnight вот вам живой пример - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ru.stackoverflow.com&s=151.101.129.69&hideResults=on&latest - в списке наборов шифров на самом верху TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256   - если бы на ru.stackoverflow.com была включена аутентификация по сертификатам - использовался бы именно RSA + AES.

Comment: @PashaPash, я имею в виду именно на шарпе) Как использовать ключ rsa в Aes

Comment: @rudnight с точки зрения AES ключ RSA - это какие-то байты. И наоборот. AES вообще все равно, что в качестве ключа отдается - главное, чтобы по длине подошло.